# I want to display a message to confirm the delete

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

first of all, even if i want to display a message  after click on the table, nothing happened. i didn't understand what is missing for this first step.
At the end, i want to confirm the delete after click on the button delete.
There is my code for each files html.twig and js

main.js:

```
   var produits = document.getElementById('produits');

   if (produits) {
         produits.addEventListener('click', e => {
          // if (e.target.className === 'btn btn-danger') {
          //     if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
          //         const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
          //
          //         fetch(`/Delete/${id}`, {
          //
          //   }).then(res => window.location.reload());
          //}
          // }
    alert(2);
         });
    }
```

Affiche.html.twig:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="produits">

                        <tr>

                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Desctiption</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Operation</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>

                        </tr>


                        {%  for produit in produits %}

                            <tr>

                                <td>{{ produit.nomProduit }}</td>

                                <td>{{ produit.descriptionProduit }}</td>

                                <td><img alt="" src="{{ asset('uploads/images/'~produit.imageProduit) }}"></td>

                                <td>{{ produit.operationProduit }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-info" id="button">Show</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                    <a href="Supprimer/{{ produit.idProduit }}" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="{{ produit.idProduit }}">Delete</a>
                                </td>


                            </tr>

                        {% endfor %}



                    </table>
```

Comment: And what is the problem with all that code?

Comment: the "alert(2)" doesn't work

Comment: What does that mean? How is that related to PHP or Symfony after all?

Comment: you have to add and id=''produits" do the delete button for this to work, because all i can see an id there and you want to select the element with id, which is not present

Answer (score 1):

1. An ID is by definition unique, here it seems you can have more than one product so you should set a class to target them all. And moreover you set a "data-id" and not an id. I used "produits-alerte" in my example.
2. Select products by class and loop over them to add an onClick event, so you can both trigger dialog and get the specific id of the product clicked.

So it leads to :

```
for (var i = 0, len = produits_alerte.length; i < len; i++) {  
    produits_alerte[i].onclick = function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

            console.log('Product ID Clicked : ' + this.getAttribute("data-id"));

            //delete product with id above

        } else {

            //or don't

        }
    } 
}
```

[Here is a working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0sjkqrub/1/) using only vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

create a function:

```
    <script>
      function getvalue() {
        alert("Hi");
        return;
      }
    </script>
```

Link it to the button with 'onClick':

```
<a href="Supprimer/{{ produit.idProduit }}" class="btn btn-danger" data-id="{{ produit.idProduit }}" onClick="getvalue()">Delete</a>
```